# How to disable script on mobiles

Tags: javascript, dom, mobile

I have a script running on a page in which for mobiles id like to disable; I've looked around and haven't found a solution yet.

The script is as follows:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
        const x = event.pageX
        const y = event.pageY

        document.querySelectorAll(".c-letter").forEach(div => {
            const dx = (div.offsetLeft + 50) - x
            const dy = (div.offsetTop + 50) - y
            const dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)

            const score = Math.exp(dist * -0.005)

            div.style.transform = "scale(" + score + ")"
            div.style.fontWeight = 100 + (100 * Math.round(8 * score))
        })
    })
</script>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by 'mobiles'. You can get the name of the device you're on, that's called user agent sniffing, and then say 'if this is an iphone, or a galaxy, or an LG', etc, etc, but that's not future-proof - when new devices come out you won't know about them.

It's better to do feature detection - why is your code not wanted on mobiles? The screen's too small? It's a touchscreen instead of a mouse? These are the things you should test for.

You're using a mousemove event, so looks like you may want to disable that on touchscreens. You can do it like this:

```
if ( !('ontouchstart' in window ) ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, it was generally that i wanted to disable the mousemove event for all devises which weren't desktops. So think it could be something i could disable by screen width too? if thats possible. I'll try the code though, thanks